# Brackets: How to change CTRL+TAB behaviour

Tags: brackets

When using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> the editor opens recent documents instead of going through the recent open ones.

I would like to prevent opening new files, from the usability point this is quite irritating.

In the following you see that the shortcut opens a new file instead of staying within the open files:

[image: brackets]

I know that I could use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd> to only go through the open documents, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> is much faster since I can use this shortcut by only one hand.

Answer (score 0):

Open **Debug** > **Open User Key Map**
and in *overrides* section add this:

```
"Ctrl-Tab": "navigate.nextDocListOrder",
"Ctrl-Shift-Tab": "navigate.prevDocListOrder"
```